# Why margin collapsing doesn't work? What am I missing?

Tags: html, css, block, margin

I've read about margin collapsing and I decided to check how it works. So, I have my parent element and child element. In the first case everything works.

**margin-top**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And now I can see this margin in my devtools, but actually it doesn't work...

**margin-bottom**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.child_2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: purple;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

What can explain this behviour?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins: *bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has 'auto' computed height* --> you parent doesn't have a height auto

Comment: @Temani Afif Can I ask you something else? [The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) tells us that two margins are collpsing if _"The bottom margin of an in-flow block box with a 'height' of 'auto' and a **'min-height' of zero** collapses with its last in-flow block-level child's bottom margin if the box has no bottom padding and no bottom border and the child's bottom margin does not collapse with a top margin that has clearance."_ But as for min-height I can't say that the spec tells us the truth. [Look](https://jsfiddle.net/doe4w31h/)